# A addEventListener won't work in a html jQuery dark-light switcher

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried redoing an "dark-light" mode toggler I got from a codepen. Originally the toggler used a onclick in the html to activate but that didn't work so I tried makeing a addEventListener to solve the issue but now I realised that didn't work either, I also tried making it with a jQuery on() but I could not get that to work (probably my fault). So now i'm asking what would be the simplest way of solving this.

Html:

```
                <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
                  <span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#main").toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

  document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener("click", darkLight);

  function darkLight() {
    if (localStorage.toggled != "dark") {
      $("body").toggleClass("dark", true);
      localStorage.toggled = "dark";
    } else {
      $("body").toggleClass("dark", false);
      localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
  }

  /*Add 'checked' property to input if background == dark*/
  if ($("main").hasClass("dark")) {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", false);
  }

});
```

Comment: `$("#main").toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);` doesn't seem right. When the locla storage variable is set, every time you reload the page you'll switch between dark and light mode.

Comment: What you want is `$("#main").toggleClass("dark", localStorage.toggled == 'dark')`

Comment: That doesn't fix the addEventListened problem tho, but thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? The question isn't very clear about it. "didn't work" is not a good problem description. Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Yes im sorry I didn't mention it in the original post, this is what I get in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:10:38)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30310)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30612)

Comment: IDs are case-sensitive. You have `id="checkBox"`, but you're using `checkbox` in the `addEventListener()` call.

Comment: Oh, my fault! Sorry you had to go through with this just because I missed that but thanks